# how to import a python file which is further importing other files. without getting ImportError?

Tags: python, import

I have a python file say `a.py` , i need to use all the functions defined in `b.py` so , i did sys.path.append(path/to/b.py/folder) , `b.py` also imports certain python files .

i am getting error when `b.py` is trying to import `c.py` (`c.py` happens to be in the same folder path)

```
 a.py :
    import b


   b.py :
    import c
```

> Error:  ImportError: No module named c

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `relative import` in this case.

just write in `b.py`

`from . import c`

it will do the job